# Downloading a docx file via react.js

Tags: reactjs, docx

Hi i have been trying to download a word file via react.js but when i press submit and it downloades it cant open the word file. The console.logs looks completely fine. If i open the file in notepad it just says readablestream. All help appreciated

```
onSubmit = () =>{

    let data = {data: this.state}

    console.log(data)

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

    fetch(this.state.endpoint,{method: 'post', headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: JSON.stringify(data)}).then((response) =>{

    var blob = new Blob([response], {"Content-type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" });

    saveAs(blob, "dynamic.docx")}

  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use [response.blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob)

I tried it with ExpressJs server:

```
app.post(url, (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name } = req.body
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + "/" + name)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("req/res", e)
  }
})
```

and React:

- add preventDefault to onSubmit
- made custom saveAs()
- used response.blob()

  ```
   const saveAs = (blob, name) => {
    const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    const a = document.createElement("a")
    a.href = downloadUrl
    a.download = name
    a.click()
  }
  const onSubmit = e => {
   e.preventDefault()
   fetch("http://localhost:5000/getfile", { method: "post", headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, body: JSON.stringify(data) }).then(response => {
     response.blob().then(blob => {
       saveAs(blob, "test.docx")
     })
   })
  }
  ```

Hope something of this will help, happy coding:)